# How can I set a heading structure with children via HTML Agility Package in Asp Core 3.1?

Tags: asp.net-core, html-agility-pack

```
 public List<HtmlNode> GetHeadersFromBlogHTML(string html)
    {
        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);
        var xpath = "//*[self::h1 or self::h2 or self::h3 or self::h4]";
        HtmlNodeCollection headers = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath);
        if (headers == null || headers.Count == 0)
            return null;

        var headerList = headers
                     .Where(node => !"a".Equals(node.PreviousSibling?.OriginalName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                     .ToList();

        return headerList;
    }
```

Headers

```
    var headers = _uow.Blog.GetHeadersFromBlogHTML(blog.Description);
```

---

```
    @foreach (var item in headers)
    {
        <li>@item.OriginalName</li>
    }
```

Output of List;

```
<ul>
                                               <li>h2</li>
                                               <li>h2</li>
                                               <li>h2</li>
                                               <li>h3</li>
                                               <li>h3</li>
                                               <li>h2</li>
                                               <li>h2</li>
                                        </ul>
```

I get List via HtmlAgility Package. I would like to create a heading structure with children like this.

> ```
> h2 --> Heading 2.1
>       h3 --> Heading 3.1
> h2 --> Heading 2.2
>       h3 --> Heading 3.2
>       h3 --> Heading 3.3
>             h4 --> Heading 4.1
> ....
> ```

How can I set a structure via HTML Agility Pack with children

Comment: It seems that  you want to display a parent and child structure, if that is the case, you might need to use nested foreach statement to loop through the parent node and its child node, then display the header. Refer the following links: [@functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-6.0#functions) and [Iterating through list within Razor View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36643803/iterating-through-list-within-razor-view).

Comment: Thank you. I will try